# Overlay confetti jaravascript, without blocking clicks and such

Tags: javascript, css

I've been using a few different javascript tools to generate confetti and celebration effect. All of those are some kind of overlay graphics. which block clicks of buttons, links and so on. Is there any way to keep a layer in front but ignore the actual clicks on that element, or allow clicks through the animated layer.

Script example im trying to use now is: http://codepen.io/iprodev/full/azpWBr/

**html example**

```
<canvas height='1' id='confetti' width='1'></canvas>
```

**css**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#confetti{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var retina = window.devicePixelRatio,

    // Math shorthands
    PI = Math.PI,
    sqrt = Math.sqrt,
    round = Math.round,
    random = Math.random,
    cos = Math.cos,
    sin = Math.sin,

    // Local WindowAnimationTiming interface
    rAF = window.requestAnimationFrame,
    cAF = window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.cancelRequestAnimationFrame,
    _now = Date.now || function () {return new Date().getTime();};

// Local WindowAnimationTiming interface polyfill
(function (w) {
  /**
                * Fallback implementation.
                */
  var prev = _now();
  function fallback(fn) {
    var curr = _now();
    var ms = Math.max(0, 16 - (curr - prev));
    var req = setTimeout(fn, ms);
    prev = curr;
    return req;
  }

  /**
                * Cancel.
                */
  var cancel = w.cancelAnimationFrame
  || w.webkitCancelAnimationFrame
  || w.clearTimeout;

  rAF = w.requestAnimationFrame
  || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
  || fallback;

  cAF = function(id){
    cancel.call(w, id);
  };
}(window));

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var speed = 50,
      duration = (1.0 / speed),
      confettiRibbonCount = 11,
      ribbonPaperCount = 30,
      ribbonPaperDist = 8.0,
      ribbonPaperThick = 8.0,
      confettiPaperCount = 95,
      DEG_TO_RAD = PI / 180,
      RAD_TO_DEG = 180 / PI,
      colors = [
        ["#df0049", "#660671"],
        ["#00e857", "#005291"],
        ["#2bebbc", "#05798a"],
        ["#ffd200", "#b06c00"]
      ];

  function Vector2(_x, _y) {
    this.x = _x, this.y = _y;
    this.Length = function() {
      return sqrt(this.SqrLength());
    }
    this.SqrLength = function() {
      return this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y;
    }
    this.Add = function(_vec) {
      this.x += _vec.x;
      this.y += _vec.y;
    }
    this.Sub = function(_vec) {
      this.x -= _vec.x;
      this.y -= _vec.y;
    }
    this.Div = function(_f) {
      this.x /= _f;
      this.y /= _f;
    }
    this.Mul = function(_f) {
      this.x *= _f;
      this.y *= _f;
    }
    this.Normalize = function() {
      var sqrLen = this.SqrLength();
      if (sqrLen != 0) {
        var factor = 1.0 / sqrt(sqrLen);
        this.x *= factor;
        this.y *= factor;
      }
    }
    this.Normalized = function() {
      var sqrLen = this.SqrLength();
      if (sqrLen != 0) {
        var factor = 1.0 / sqrt(sqrLen);
        return new Vector2(this.x * factor, this.y * factor);
      }
      return new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
  }
  Vector2.Lerp = function(_vec0, _vec1, _t) {
    return new Vector2((_vec1.x - _vec0.x) * _t + _vec0.x, (_vec1.y - _vec0.y) * _t + _vec0.y);
  }
  Vector2.Distance = function(_vec0, _vec1) {
    return sqrt(Vector2.SqrDistance(_vec0, _vec1));
  }
  Vector2.SqrDistance = function(_vec0, _vec1) {
    var x = _vec0.x - _vec1.x;
    var y = _vec0.y - _vec1.y;
    return (x * x + y * y + z * z);
  }
  Vector2.Scale = function(_vec0, _vec1) {
    return new Vector2(_vec0.x * _vec1.x, _vec0.y * _vec1.y);
  }
  Vector2.Min = function(_vec0, _vec1) {
    return new Vector2(Math.min(_vec0.x, _vec1.x), Math.min(_vec0.y, _vec1.y));
  }
  Vector2.Max = function(_vec0, _vec1) {
    return new Vector2(Math.max(_vec0.x, _vec1.x), Math.max(_vec0.y, _vec1.y));
  }
  Vector2.ClampMagnitude = function(_vec0, _len) {
    var vecNorm = _vec0.Normalized;
    return new Vector2(vecNorm.x * _len, vecNorm.y * _len);
  }
  Vector2.Sub = function(_vec0, _vec1) {
    return new Vector2(_vec0.x - _vec1.x, _vec0.y - _vec1.y, _vec0.z - _vec1.z);
  }

  function EulerMass(_x, _y, _mass, _drag) {
    this.position = new Vector2(_x, _y);
    this.mass = _mass;
    this.drag = _drag;
    this.force = new Vector2(0, 0);
    this.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    this.AddForce = function(_f) {
      this.force.Add(_f);
    }
    this.Integrate = function(_dt) {
      var acc = this.CurrentForce(this.position);
      acc.Div(this.mass);
      var posDelta = new Vector2(this.velocity.x, this.velocity.y);
      posDelta.Mul(_dt);
      this.position.Add(posDelta);
      acc.Mul(_dt);
      this.velocity.Add(acc);
      this.force = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
    this.CurrentForce = function(_pos, _vel) {
      var totalForce = new Vector2(this.force.x, this.force.y);
      var speed = this.velocity.Length();
      var dragVel = new Vector2(this.velocity.x, this.velocity.y);
      dragVel.Mul(this.drag * this.mass * speed);
      totalForce.Sub(dragVel);
      return totalForce;
    }
  }

  function ConfettiPaper(_x, _y) {
    this.pos = new Vector2(_x, _y);
    this.rotationSpeed = (random() * 600 + 800);
    this.angle = DEG_TO_RAD * random() * 360;
    this.rotation = DEG_TO_RAD * random() * 360;
    this.cosA = 1.0;
    this.size = 5.0;
    this.oscillationSpeed = (random() * 1.5 + 0.5);
    this.xSpeed = 40.0;
    this.ySpeed = (random() * 60 + 50.0);
    this.corners = new Array();
    this.time = random();
    var ci = round(random() * (colors.length - 1));
    this.frontColor = colors[ci][0];
    this.backColor = colors[ci][1];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var dx = cos(this.angle + DEG_TO_RAD * (i * 90 + 45));
      var dy = sin(this.angle + DEG_TO_RAD * (i * 90 + 45));
      this.corners[i] = new Vector2(dx, dy);
    }
    this.Update = function(_dt) {
      this.time += _dt;
      this.rotation += this.rotationSpeed * _dt;
      this.cosA = cos(DEG_TO_RAD * this.rotation);
      this.pos.x += cos(this.time * this.oscillationSpeed) * this.xSpeed * _dt
      this.pos.y += this.ySpeed * _dt;
      if (this.pos.y > ConfettiPaper.bounds.y) {
        this.pos.x = random() * ConfettiPaper.bounds.x;
        this.pos.y = 0;
      }
    }
    this.Draw = function(_g) {
      if (this.cosA > 0) {
        _g.fillStyle = this.frontColor;
      } else {
        _g.fillStyle = this.backColor;
      }
      _g.beginPath();
      _g.moveTo((this.pos.x + this.corners[0].x * this.size) * retina, (this.pos.y + this.corners[0].y * this.size * this.cosA) * retina);
      for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        _g.lineTo((this.pos.x + this.corners[i].x * this.size) * retina, (this.pos.y + this.corners[i].y * this.size * this.cosA) * retina);
      }
      _g.closePath();
      _g.fill();
    }
  }
  ConfettiPaper.bounds = new Vector2(0, 0);

  function ConfettiRibbon(_x, _y, _count, _dist, _thickness, _angle, _mass, _drag) {
    this.particleDist = _dist;
    this.particleCount = _count;
    this.particleMass = _mass;
    this.particleDrag = _drag;
    this.particles = new Array();
    var ci = round(random() * (colors.length - 1));
    this.frontColor = colors[ci][0];
    this.backColor = colors[ci][1];
    this.xOff = (cos(DEG_TO_RAD * _angle) * _thickness);
    this.yOff = (sin(DEG_TO_RAD * _angle) * _thickness);
    this.position = new Vector2(_x, _y);
    this.prevPosition = new Vector2(_x, _y);
    this.velocityInherit = (random() * 2 + 4);
    this.time = random() * 100;
    this.oscillationSpeed = (random() * 2 + 2);
    this.oscillationDistance = (random() * 40 + 40);
    this.ySpeed = (random() * 40 + 80);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.particleCount; i++) {
      this.particles[i] = new EulerMass(_x, _y - i * this.particleDist, this.particleMass, this.particleDrag);
    }
    this.Update = function(_dt) {
      var i = 0;
      this.time += _dt * this.oscillationSpeed;
      this.position.y += this.ySpeed * _dt;
      this.position.x += cos(this.time) * this.oscillationDistance * _dt;
      this.particles[0].position = this.position;
      var dX = this.prevPosition.x - this.position.x;
      var dY = this.prevPosition.y - this.position.y;
      var delta = sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);
      this.prevPosition = new Vector2(this.position.x, this.position.y);
      for (i = 1; i < this.particleCount; i++) {
        var dirP = Vector2.Sub(this.particles[i - 1].position, this.particles[i].position);
        dirP.Normalize();
        dirP.Mul((delta / _dt) * this.velocityInherit);
        this.particles[i].AddForce(dirP);
      }
      for (i = 1; i < this.particleCount; i++) {
        this.particles[i].Integrate(_dt);
      }
      for (i = 1; i < this.particleCount; i++) {
        var rp2 = new Vector2(this.particles[i].position.x, this.particles[i].position.y);
        rp2.Sub(this.particles[i - 1].position);
        rp2.Normalize();
        rp2.Mul(this.particleDist);
        rp2.Add(this.particles[i - 1].position);
        this.particles[i].position = rp2;
      }
      if (this.position.y > ConfettiRibbon.bounds.y + this.particleDist * this.particleCount) {
        this.Reset();
      }
    }
    this.Reset = function() {
      this.position.y = -random() * ConfettiRibbon.bounds.y;
      this.position.x = random() * ConfettiRibbon.bounds.x;
      this.prevPosition = new Vector2(this.position.x, this.position.y);
      this.velocityInherit = random() * 2 + 4;
      this.time = random() * 100;
      this.oscillationSpeed = random() * 2.0 + 1.5;
      this.oscillationDistance = (random() * 40 + 40);
      this.ySpeed = random() * 40 + 80;
      var ci = round(random() * (colors.length - 1));
      this.frontColor = colors[ci][0];
      this.backColor = colors[ci][1];
      this.particles = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < this.particleCount; i++) {
        this.particles[i] = new EulerMass(this.position.x, this.position.y - i * this.particleDist, this.particleMass, this.particleDrag);
      }
    }
    this.Draw = function(_g) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.particleCount - 1; i++) {
        var p0 = new Vector2(this.particles[i].position.x + this.xOff, this.particles[i].position.y + this.yOff);
        var p1 = new Vector2(this.particles[i + 1].position.x + this.xOff, this.particles[i + 1].position.y + this.yOff);
        if (this.Side(this.particles[i].position.x, this.particles[i].position.y, this.particles[i + 1].position.x, this.particles[i + 1].position.y, p1.x, p1.y) < 0) {
          _g.fillStyle = this.frontColor;
          _g.strokeStyle = this.frontColor;
        } else {
          _g.fillStyle = this.backColor;
          _g.strokeStyle = this.backColor;
        }
        if (i == 0) {
          _g.beginPath();
          _g.moveTo(this.particles[i].position.x * retina, this.particles[i].position.y * retina);
          _g.lineTo(this.particles[i + 1].position.x * retina, this.particles[i + 1].position.y * retina);
          _g.lineTo(((this.particles[i + 1].position.x + p1.x) * 0.5) * retina, ((this.particles[i + 1].position.y + p1.y) * 0.5) * retina);
          _g.closePath();
          _g.stroke();
          _g.fill();
          _g.beginPath();
          _g.moveTo(p1.x * retina, p1.y * retina);
          _g.lineTo(p0.x * retina, p0.y * retina);
          _g.lineTo(((this.particles[i + 1].position.x + p1.x) * 0.5) * retina, ((this.particles[i + 1].position.y + p1.y) * 0.5) * retina);
          _g.closePath();
          _g.stroke();
          _g.fill();
        } else if (i == this.particleCount - 2) {
          _g.beginPath();
          _g.moveTo(this.particles[i].position.x * retina, this.particles[i].position.y * retina);
          _g.lineTo(this.particles[i + 1].position.x * retina, this.particles[i + 1].position.y * retina);
          _g.lineTo(((this.particles[i].position.x + p0.x) * 0.5) * retina, ((this.particles[i].position.y + p0.y) * 0.5) * retina);
          _g.closePath();
          _g.stroke();
          _g.fill();
          _g.beginPath();
          _g.moveTo(p1.x * retina, p1.y * retina);
          _g.lineTo(p0.x * retina, p0.y * retina);
          _g.lineTo(((this.particles[i].position.x + p0.x) * 0.5) * retina, ((this.particles[i].position.y + p0.y) * 0.5) * retina);
          _g.closePath();
          _g.stroke();
          _g.fill();
        } else {
          _g.beginPath();
          _g.moveTo(this.particles[i].position.x * retina, this.particles[i].position.y * retina);
          _g.lineTo(this.particles[i + 1].position.x * retina, this.particles[i + 1].position.y * retina);
          _g.lineTo(p1.x * retina, p1.y * retina);
          _g.lineTo(p0.x * retina, p0.y * retina);
          _g.closePath();
          _g.stroke();
          _g.fill();
        }
      }
    }
    this.Side = function(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {
      return ((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y2) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x2));
    }
  }
  ConfettiRibbon.bounds = new Vector2(0, 0);
  confetti = {};
  confetti.Context = function(id) {
    var i = 0;
    var canvas = document.getElementById(id);
    var canvasParent = canvas.parentNode;
    var canvasWidth = canvasParent.offsetWidth;
    var canvasHeight = canvasParent.offsetHeight;
    canvas.width = canvasWidth * retina;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight * retina;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var interval = null;
    var confettiRibbons = new Array();
    ConfettiRibbon.bounds = new Vector2(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    for (i = 0; i < confettiRibbonCount; i++) {
      confettiRibbons[i] = new ConfettiRibbon(random() * canvasWidth, -random() * canvasHeight * 2, ribbonPaperCount, ribbonPaperDist, ribbonPaperThick, 45, 1, 0.05);
    }
    var confettiPapers = new Array();
    ConfettiPaper.bounds = new Vector2(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    for (i = 0; i < confettiPaperCount; i++) {
      confettiPapers[i] = new ConfettiPaper(random() * canvasWidth, random() * canvasHeight);
    }
    this.resize = function() {
      canvasWidth = canvasParent.offsetWidth;
      canvasHeight = canvasParent.offsetHeight;
      canvas.width = canvasWidth * retina;
      canvas.height = canvasHeight * retina;
      ConfettiPaper.bounds = new Vector2(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
      ConfettiRibbon.bounds = new Vector2(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    }
    this.start = function() {
      this.stop()
      var context = this;
      this.update();
    }
    this.stop = function() {
      cAF(this.interval);
    }
    this.update = function() {
      var i = 0;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      for (i = 0; i < confettiPaperCount; i++) {
        confettiPapers[i].Update(duration);
        confettiPapers[i].Draw(context);
      }
      for (i = 0; i < confettiRibbonCount; i++) {
        confettiRibbons[i].Update(duration);
        confettiRibbons[i].Draw(context);
      }
      this.interval = rAF(function() {
        confetti.update();
      });
    }
  }
  var confetti = new confetti.Context('confetti');
  confetti.start();
  window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    confetti.resize();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) css property, try:

`pointer-events: none`

Comment: Been searching for hours but sometimes things are so darn easy! thanks for this.